# Trouble handling JQuery Event targets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I'm trying to create a universal handler for my buttons,
but the following code doesn't seem to recognize the event targets,
and instead spits out the target.toString() == the current page URL?

html:

```
<a id="button1" href="#"></a>
<a id="button2" href="#"></a>
```

jquery/javascript:

```
function myHandler(e) {

   if (e.target == $("#button1")) 
      alert("Button 1 clicked");
   else if (e.target == $("#button2")) 
      alert("Button 2 clicked");
   else
      alert(e.target.toString());
}

$("#button1").click(myHandler);
$("#button2").click(myHandler);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function myHandler(e) {

   if (e.target.id == "button1")
      alert("Button 1 clicked");
   else if (e.target.id == "button2")
      alert("Button 2 clicked");
   else
      alert(e.target.toString());
}

$("#button1").click(myHandler);
$("#button2").click(myHandler);
```

your code cannot work because you are comparing the target event with a jQuery object

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/7b53z/

Comment: fcalderan- thanks very much for the jsfiddle example- didn't even know about that site.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues with your code.

1. you missed the `#` for the ids inside your `myHandler`.
2. you are comparing dom elements *`e.target`* with jquery objects *`$('..')`*.

Use

```
function myHandler(e) {

   if (e.target == $("#button1")[0]) 
      alert("Button 1 clicked");
   else if (e.target == $("#button2")[0]) 
      alert("Button 2 clicked");
   else
      alert(e.target.toString());
}
```

Comment: thanks- 1 was a mis-copy of my code, I fixed it.  2- I thought I would be getting a JQuery.Event object, and that the .target property on that would be the same sort of reference as a $('') reference?

Comment: @Yarin ,look at http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ They mention that some properties have been normalized for *cross-browser consistency*. Also look at http://api.jquery.com/event.target/ **Description:** *The DOM element that initiated the event*

Comment: Thanks alot- both your and fcalderan's answers worked well, but I gave it to him for being first.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a demo with jsFiddle - **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/uccYG/2/)**

and the code from the demo below:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function eventHandler(e){
    var clicked = $(e.target);

    // will check if element is or is a child of event target        
    if (clicked.is('#btn1') || clicked.parents().is('#btn1'))
      console.log("btn1 was clicked");
    else if(clicked.is('#btn2') || clicked.parents().is('#btn2'))
      console.log("btn2 was clicked");
  }

  $('#btn1').bind('click', function(e){
    eventHandler(e);
    return false;
  });

  $('#btn2').bind('click', function(e){
    eventHandler(e);
    return false;
  });

});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="btn1">Button #1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button #2</button>
```

Hopefully this helps. If you need a non-jQuery version let me know.